# Firebase Realtime Database, can't check the db for existing data and push if not existent

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a couple of edit texts, two time picker and two date pickers, all for of them are restricted (time and date pickers). Two time and date pickers are used for the Cat time and date and the other two are used for the Dog time and date. Started to use Firebase and it all worked fine, If I send the data from the edit text and time and date pickers, the data is stored just fine.

This is how my Firebase Realtime Data looks:

[image]

As you can see every time I add another set of data (like: userName, userTime, userData) it stores in the user child, and depending on the button selected it is stored in the Dog or Cats child, and of course every set of data comes with a user ID.
The ting is I dont' know how to check if the time and date picked by the user is the same with the time and date that I have in my database. I tried but every time with no success.

```
public void UserInput () {

    String phone = phoneNumber.getText().toString().trim();
    String consult = consultationMotiv.getText().toString().trim();
    String timpePick = pickTimeTextView.getText().toString().trim();
    String datePick = pickDateTextView.getText().toString().trim();
    String fullName = name.getText().toString().trim();
    String group = allAnimals.getText().toString().trim();

final String id = mDatabaseReference.push().getKey();

            final User user = new User(id, fullName, datePick, timpePick, consult, phone, group);
```

to store data depending on the time picker that the user chose, I put a text view that would get data depending on what date and time picker was selected.
Ex: If the user selected the Dog time and date picker, the textview would store the data "Dogs", if they would click the Cat time and date picker, it will store "Cats"

```
 if (allAnimals.getText().equals("Dogs")) {
                // send to userGroup DogCats
mDatabaseReference.child("users").child("Dog").
                        addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                        if (dataSnapshot.exists()) {
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Exists", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            mDatabaseReference.child("users").child("Dog").child(id).setValue(user);

                        } else {
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Select another hour", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }

                    }


                    @Override
                    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                    }
                });
```

But the data still ads even if all of it is the same. I tried this to:

```
mDatabaseReference.child("users").child("Dog").equalTo(timpePick + datePick).
                        addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                        if (dataSnapshot.exists()) {
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Exists", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            mDatabaseReference.child("users").child("Dog").child(id).setValue(user);

                        } else {
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Select another hour", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }

                    }


                    @Override
                    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                    }
                });
```

But the data doesn't add at all and I end up getting the toast "Select another hour" even if I change the hour and the time.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So i tried implemented it to my existing project and i manage to listen to value existence. Here is my code for reference

```
public void getMessageThreads() {
    threadRef = database.getReference("Thread")
            .child("Anna Baclayon");
    threadRef.orderByChild("time").equalTo("Mar 02, 2018 09:32:56").addValueEventListener(threadListener);
}

ValueEventListener threadListener = new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        chatUsers.clear();
        for (DataSnapshot messageThread : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            String time = (String) messageThread.child("time").getValue();

            if(time.contains("Mar 02, 2018 09:32:56")){
                Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Exists", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }else
                Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Doesnt Exists", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks! I tried it, It still ads another set of data every time and it doesn't show me the Toast messages when the data is already stored

Comment: check my editted answer.. Be sure to make pick_time same format as the saved one

Comment: dont forget the `.equalTo(picked_time)`

Comment: Thanks! I tried again, at this point I don't know what I'm doing wrong. In the onDataChange, when I try to add the child, it doesn't work. I get this (Cannot resolve method 'child(java.lang.String)).
I am reffering to:   if ((dataSnapshot.getChildren().*here*child("userTime").getValue()).contains(picked_time))

Comment: `DataSnapshot item = dataSnapshot.getChildren()` then `item.child("userTime")`

Comment: P.s. I added the `equalTo()` still no luck.

Comment: Check final edit. I tested it myself. I used reference that would match yours so ignore my reference